# Display Unicode characters in SQL Developer's query-result pane

Tags: oracle, unicode, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to display Unicode characters in SQL Developer's query-result panel.

Jeff Smith's [Non-English Character Display in Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/08/non-english-character-display-in-oracle-sql-developer/) posting suggests that it's just a matter of choosing the correct font.  I've select `consolas`:

[image]

This setting appears to have an effect in the worksheet:

[image]

But not in the results:

[image]

Desired:

```
ORDER_NAME  MIN_ORDER_DATE  MAX_ORDER_DATE  SPARKLINE
ORDER A 2016-12-01  2017-03-02  ⣀⣴⣀⣀
ORDER B 2017-03-01  2017-03-01  ⣾
```

Code snippet:

```
with

orders as (
    select order_name, order_id, to_date(ORDER_date,'mm/dd/yy') order_date
          ,extract(year from to_date(ORDER_date,'mm/dd/yy')) year, extract(month from to_date(ORDER_date,'mm/dd/yy')) month
    from (
      select 'ORDER A' order_name, 1 order_id, '12/01/16' ORDER_date FROM DUAL
      union ALL
      select 'ORDER A' order_name, 2 order_id, '01/02/17' ORDER_date FROM DUAL
      union ALL
      select 'ORDER A' order_name, 3 order_id, '01/03/17' ORDER_date FROM DUAL
      union ALL
      select 'ORDER A' order_name, 4 order_id, '01/01/17' ORDER_date FROM DUAL
      union ALL
      select 'ORDER A' order_name, 5 order_id, '02/02/17' ORDER_date FROM DUAL
      union ALL
      select 'ORDER A' order_name, 6 order_id, '03/02/17' ORDER_date FROM DUAL
      union ALL
      select 'ORDER B' order_name, 7 order_id, '03/01/17' ORDER_date FROM DUAL
    ) v
  )

select

        order_name
        , min(min_order_date) min_order_date, max(max_order_date) max_order_date
          ,listagg(
              case
                when percent_total=0 then '⠀'
                when percent_total < 1/8 then '⡀'
                when percent_total < 2/8 then '⣀'
                when percent_total < 3/8 then '⣠'
                when percent_total < 4/8 then '⣤'
                when percent_total < 5/8 then '⣴'
                when percent_total < 6/8 then '⣶'
                when percent_total < 7/8 then '⣾'
                else '⣿'
              end,'') within group (order by year, month) SPARKLINE
FROM    (
  SELECT  order_name, year, month, min_order_date, max_order_date
          , monthly_orders, sum(monthly_orders) over (PARTITION BY order_name) total_orders
          ,monthly_orders / sum(monthly_orders) over (PARTITION BY order_name) percent_total
  FROM  (
    SELECT  order_name, year, month, count(order_id) monthly_orders, min(order_date) min_order_date, max(order_date) max_order_date
    FROM    orders o
    group by order_name, year, month
  ) v0
) v1
group by order_name
order by order_name
```

What am I missing?

### edit 0

I'm using SQL Developer 4.1.3.20 on OS X Sierra (10.12.6).

### edit 1

I tried a number of different fonts, which appear to work in Preferences, but have no effect on the query-results pane:

#### Consolas

[image]

#### Apple Braille

[image]

#### DialogInput

[image]

### edit 2

#### OS X

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

#### Windows

```
C:\> java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

### edit 3

```
select * from v$nls_parameters

PARAMETER VALUE
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
```

Comment: Try setting `DialogInput` font.

Answer (score 2):

I stand by my answer.

[image]

Paste your Braille characters in the preview text area in the preferences and then roll through the list until you find one that works.

For me, Consolas on Windows 10 does NOT pass this test.

The code editor font apply to both editors and grids in SQL Developer.

Comment: funny dominoes = braille

Comment: I tried the query on a Windows 7 Enterprise machine using the Segoe UI Symbol font.  Similar results--Unicode characters are displayed the query worksheet, but not in the results.

Comment: I tried on Windows 10:  `SanSerif` and `Monospaced` and `Dialog`, they worked in the editor, query results tab and script output tab.

Comment: @craig which Look and Feel are you running? I'm using windows look and feel in preferences, but that SHOULD have no effect

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, both were set to `oracle`.  Changed one to `windows` and the other to `mac os x`.  No effect.

Comment: Characters are not correctly displayed in script (`F5`) results either.

Comment: You can also use this page to find out which font supports desired characters: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm

Comment: my best guess now is that your db itself isn't setup for unicode correctly